# How to call a function on an object with a generic type parameter using scala macros?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-macros

Consider the following two classes, both of them have a `parseFrom` function.

```
class X {}
object X {
  def parseFrom(b: Array[Byte]): String = "Hello"
}

class Y {}

object Y {
  def parseFrom(b: Array[Byte]): String = "HelloY"
}
```

I want to write a macro:
`getParseFrom[X]` that will return the `X.parseFrom` function.

This is what I have so far:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

def getParseFromImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val tpe = weakTypeOf[T]

  q"""
     $tpe.parseFrom(_)
   """
}

def getParseFrom[T]: Array[Byte] => String = macro getParseFromImpl[T]
```

Is this possible with scala macros in scala 2.12?

Comment: What about creating a simple **typeclass** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
q"""
  ${tpe.typeSymbol.companion}.parseFrom(_)
"""
```

Comment: What would I do if parseFrom was a java static method on a java class X as opposed a method on a companion object?